# Memeory access violation error when passing ctypes struct to win32 API in python

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes

I have written a simple command line application in python, it creates a new process by calling win32 API, the application exits and throws a memory access violation error when calling the function CreateProcess with ctypes wrapper, the code is as follows:

```
from ctypes import windll, byref, POINTER, GetLastError, Structure, sizeof,Union,pointer
from ctypes.wintypes import (
  LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, WCHAR, DWORD, HANDLE, BOOL,LPCVOID,ULONG,BYTE,WORD
)
import sys
import time
class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
    _field_=[("cb",DWORD),
    ("lpReserved",LPWSTR),
    ("lpDesktop",LPWSTR),
    ("lpTitle",LPWSTR),
    ("dwX",DWORD),
    ("dwY",DWORD),
    ("dwXSize",DWORD),
    ("dwYSize",DWORD),
    ("dwXCountChars",DWORD),
    ("dwYCountChars",DWORD),
    ("dwFillAttribute",DWORD),
    ("dwFlags",DWORD),
    ("wShowWindow",WORD),
    ("cbReserved2",WORD),
    ("lpReserved2",POINTER(BYTE)),
    ("hStdInput",HANDLE),
    ("hStdOutput",HANDLE),
    ("hStdError",HANDLE)]
class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _field_=[("hProcess",HANDLE),
    ("hThread",HANDLE),
    ("dwProcessId",DWORD),
    ("dwThreadId",DWORD)]
class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(Structure):
    _field_=[("nLength",DWORD),("lpSecurityDescriptor",LPCVOID)]

HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT=0x1
STARTF_USESTDHANDLES=0x100
CreatePipe=windll.Kernel32.CreatePipe
CreatePipe.argtype=[POINTER(HANDLE),POINTER(HANDLE),POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),DWORD]
CreatePipe.restype=BOOL
SetHandleInformation=windll.Kernel32.SetHandleInformation
SetHandleInformation.argtype=[HANDLE,DWORD,DWORD]
SetHandleInformation.restype=BOOL
CloseHandle = windll.Kernel32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.argtypes = [HANDLE]
CloseHandle.restype = BOOL
CreateProcess=windll.Kernel32.CreateProcessW
CreateProcess.argtypes=[LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES),BOOL,DWORD,LPCVOID,LPCWSTR,POINTER(STARTUPINFO),POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)]
CreateProcess.restype=BOOL
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd=HANDLE()
        self.g_hChildStd_IN_Rd=HANDLE()
        self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr=HANDLE()
        self.g_hChildStd_IN_Wr=HANDLE()
    def CreateChildProcess(self):
        szCmdline = "c:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        saAttr = SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES()
        saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
        saAttr.bInheritHandle = True
        saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = None
        # Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT.
        if not CreatePipe(byref(self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd), byref(self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr), byref(saAttr), 0):
            raise Exception("failed to create console process.")
        if not SetHandleInformation(self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0):
            raise Exception("failed to create console process.")
        # Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN.
        if not CreatePipe(byref(self.g_hChildStd_IN_Rd), byref(self.g_hChildStd_IN_Wr), byref(saAttr), 0):
            raise Exception("failed to create console process.")
        if not SetHandleInformation(self.g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0):
            raise Exception("failed to create console process.")
        piProcInfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()
        siStartInfo = STARTUPINFO()
        siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        siStartInfo.hStdError = self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr
        siStartInfo.hStdOutput = self.g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr
        siStartInfo.hStdInput = self.g_hChildStd_IN_Rd
        siStartInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
        piProcInfo.hProcess = None
        piProcInfo.hThread = None
        piProcInfo.dwProcessId = 0
        piProcInfo.dwThreadId = 0
        bSuccess = CreateProcess(szCmdline,  # executable name
                                 None,  # command line name
                                 None,  # primary process security attributes
                                 None,  # primary thread security attributes
                                 True,  # handles are inherited
                                 0,  # creation flags
                                 None,  # use parent's environment
                                 None,  # use parent's current directory
                                 byref(siStartInfo),  # STARTUPINFO pointer
                                 pointer(piProcInfo)) # child process's information.  piProcInfo struct won't be modified and not contain the child process infomation after this call if I use byref here. 
        if not bSuccess:
            rc = GetLastError()
            raise Exception("failed to create console process. error code %u" % rc)
        else:
            """// Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example."""
            CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess)
            CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread)
            print "[Info] Create cmd process successfully"
            #follows some codes to write to and read from pipes
if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=test()
    obj.CreateChildProcess()
```

The stacktrace messeages are the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test01.py", line 104, in <module>
    obj.CreateChildProcess()
  File "test01.py", line 90, in CreateChildProcess
    pointer(piProcInfo)) # child process's information
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000001
```

I guess the reason for this error message is that the argument piProcInfo is not mutable to win32 API, windows function cannot modifiy the memory struct piProcInfo and fails but I'm not very sure about my guess and I don't know how to initialize a mutable memory struct and pass it as an argument to windows API, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

plus, I have tried to pass byref(piProcInfo) as an argument, but the child process information in piProcInfo structure is not changed, I need these information for further steps.

Comment: `byref` is perfectly fine. That's not the problem. The `memset` calls are pointless and probably don't help. Remove them. Initialising proc info needless, it's an out param. Assigning to `bSuccess` twice is pointless. Only the second one counts. And you only showed part of the code. Perhaps your struct definitions are wrong. [mcve] please. Until we have that MCVE it's a waste of time for anyone to dig deeper. Of course, it would be so much easier to use the `subprocess` module as nature intends ......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it will throw exception when accessing the fields of piProcInfo struct after invoking CreateProcess function if I don't initialize the fields of piProcInfo struct in advance, exception complains piProcInfo has no field xxx, I am confused about this issue too.

Comment: Well, you can see the code. We can't, because you declined to show it to us. How you can you expect us to help when we have no idea what `PROCESS_INFORMATION` is? Did you even read my comment?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sorry, I am new guy on stackoverflow, I have just read MCVE rules and will ask question in my mind in future, could you help me now?

Comment: Can I ask why you won't use subprocess?

Comment: I have several other calls to win32 API in my codes which are not available in python

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to concentrate on those then? I'm struggling to get motivated to work on needless code. Especially as you full code is so far from minimal.

Comment: @JinlxzLiu Now that you've read the MCVE rules, edit *this* question and make an MCVE.  The `memset` calls are definitely wrong.  Remove them.  `ctypes` will zero the memory when you allocate the structures, and assuming `id(siStartupInfo)` points to the start of the structure is wrong.  On CPython only, as an implementation detail, that id is the Python object wrapping the structure, not the structure itself.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the codes, you can reproduce the error from the source easily, could you help me?

Comment: Do you need the pipe code to see the error?

Comment: no need, the same error occurs even if I comment the pipe code

Comment: It's `_fields_` not `_field_`. A couple times you're using `argtype` instead of `argtypes`. The `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` definition is completely missing `bInheritHandle`. Also, don't use `windll`. Use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. Don't use `GetLastError` with a generic `Exception`. Use `raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())`. Consistently use `byref` instead of `pointer` to pass an argument by reference. And don't bother initializing fields to 0 or `None` in struct instances since ctypes zeros the allocated memory for you.

Comment: Also, learn the value of white space and clean, consistent formatting. It helps to make code legible, which may actually help you to spot errors when reviewing your own code.

Comment: @eryksun, thank you, I fixed the problem according to your advice.  There are some spelling mistakes, my fault.